# What all content PKCS#7 can have and what is the purpose of each?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, pkcs7

When signed data is packaged as PKCS#7, 
what all content PKCS#7 could be there(Ex. certificates, signature, etc.)?
And what are the purpose of packaging all those contents?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed any data within a PKCS#7/CMS structure.
The *Cryptographic Message Syntax* (which is the new name for PKCS#7) knows the types [EnvelopedData](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-6.1) for encrypted data and [AuthenticatedData](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-9) for signed/MACed data.

That way, you can create an *enveloping signature*, thus storing the signature and the signed data in a single file even when the format of your data does not support it.

Comment: When I sign a data and package it as PKCS#7 file, what all data should be there? and what is the reason behind it?

Comment: It it optional, if you actually do it, is up to the requirements of your application. As I wrote in my answer: You might want to do it, if you do not want to have a detached signature (a signature in a seperate file), but your file type does not allow to embed a signature directly.